# How to get data from all subcollection of docs of firebase in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is how my firebase database looks like]

[image: This is how my firebase database looks like]

How can I get all orders data from this database ?

This is how I have stored data :

```js
db
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user?.email)
    .collection('orders')
    .doc(paymentIntent.id)
    .set({
        basket: basket,
        amount: paymentIntent.amount,
        created: paymentIntent.created
    })

setSucceeded(true);
setError(null);
setProcessing(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Collection Group Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) might be the easiest way which fetches all documents from collections with same name which is passed in `collectionGroup()` method:

```js
db.collectionGroup("orders").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  console.log(querySnapshot.docs.map(d => ({id: d.id, ...d.data()})))
})
```

This will log an array of all orders.

Comment: Actually you're right it's more efficient to use collectionGroup. Outdated firebase version on work project brainwahsed me, lol.

Comment: you tagged the incorrect person :-)

Comment: Sorry xD My bad ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch initial collection snapshot and then get all subcollections.

If you're querying for a specific `doc` you can get a direct query result straight away:

```js
const id = 123 // 'replace with whatever user you're trying to query'
const userOrders = await firebase.collection('users').doc(id)
 .collection('orders').get()
 .then(doc => doc.exists ? doc.data() : null)
```

Otherwise you'll need to perform two consequentive fetches

```js
const ordersSnapshot = await firebase.collection('users').get()
const allOrders = await Promise.all(ordersSnapshot.docs.map(async ({ id }) => (
  firebase.collection('users').doc(id).collection('orders').get()
    .then(doc => doc.exists ? doc.data() : null)
)))
```

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        
        if (user) {
            db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user?.email)
            .collection('orders')
            .orderBy('created', 'desc')
            .onSnapshot(snapshot => (
                setOrders(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    data: doc.data()
                })))
            ))
            
        } else([])
    }, [user])

Comment: This is how I fetched data for only one doc so now what changes should I make in my code to get data from all docs ?